# How do I upload multiple files at a time in express using formidable

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, formidable

I am trying to upload files using formidable module. But when I select multiple files to upload, only the first one gets uploaded. I am new to node.

here is my upload function

```
exports.uploadPhotos = function(req, res) {
      console.log("upload received");
      var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
      form.multiples = true;

      form.parse(req, function(err, fields, files) {
        res.status(200, {
          'content-type': 'text/plain'
        });
        res.end('received upload:\n\n');
        res.end(util.inspect({
          fields: fields,
          files: files
        }));
      });

      form.on('end', function(fields, files) {
        /* Temporary location of our uploaded file */
        var temp_path = this.openedFiles[0].path;
        /* The file name of the uploaded file */
        var file_name = this.openedFiles[0].name;
        /* Location where we want to copy the uploaded file */
        var new_location = 'uploads/';

        fs.copy(temp_path, new_location + file_name, function(err) {
          if (err) {
            console.error(err);
          } else {
            console.log("success!");
          }
        });
      });
    };
```

and when I call this, following gets printed

```
received upload:

{ fields: { itemPhoto: '' },
  files: { upload: [ [Object], [Object] ] } }
```

what should I do to get all files uploaded?

Comment: not really a solution, but have you checked multer.js instead?

Comment: also, post your html form.